# PHP Echo in Href Cutting off Variable

Tags: php, href

In my form action:

```
    <form class="login" style=" ;"method="post" action=<?php echo "add_answer.php?id="; echo $id; echo "&z=$zipcode&d=$date&category=$category"; ?>">
```

$category is a 2 word variable "lawn mowing". However, it directs me to the link:

add_answer.php?id=1&z=55901&d=04/25/2014&category=Lawn

If you notice the end is "Lawn" instead of "Lawn Mowing" I made sure $category is "Lawn Mowing" as it is displayed in a header on the page. How can I fix this so the whole word is passed through the URL?

Comment: why can't you do the same thing you did with $id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/urlencode) the variables.

```
<form class="login" style=" ;"method="post" action=<?php echo "add_answer.php?id=".urlencode($id)."&z=".urlencode($zipcode)."&d=".urlencode($date)."&category=".urlencode($category); ?>">
```

###Why do I have to `urlencode()` ?

> A URI is always in an "escaped" form, since escaping or unescaping a
> completed URI might change its semantics. Normally, the only time
> escape encodings can safely be made is when the URI is being created
> from its component parts; each component may have its own set of
> characters that are reserved, so only the mechanism responsible for
> generating or interpreting that component can determine whether or not
> escaping a character will change its semantics. Likewise, a URI must
> be separated into its components before the escaped characters within
> those components can be safely decoded.
>
> In some cases, data that could be represented by an unreserved
> character may appear escaped; for example, some of the unreserved
> "mark" characters are automatically escaped by some systems. If the
> given URI scheme defines a canonicalization algorithm, then unreserved
> characters may be unescaped according to that algorithm. For example,
> "%7e" is sometimes used instead of "~" in an http URL path, but the
> two are equivalent for an http URL.
>
> Because the percent "%" character always has the reserved purpose of
> being the escape indicator, it must be escaped as "%25" in order to be
> used as data within a URI. Implementers should be careful not to
> escape or unescape the same string more than once, since unescaping an
> already unescaped string might lead to misinterpreting a percent data
> character as another escaped character, or vice versa in the case of
> escaping an already escaped string.

[`Source`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
<form class="login" style=" " method="post" action="<?php echo "add_answer.php?id=$id&z=$zipcode&d=$date&category=urlencode($category)"; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```
form class="login" style=" ;"method="post" action=<?php echo "index2.php?id=".urlencode($id)."&z=".urlencode($zipcode)."&d=".urlencode($date)."&category=".urlencode($category); ?>>
```